# cannot instanciate the type list of itextpdf

Tags: java, itextpdf

I want to display in a pdf a list of clients. I use this attribute :

```
 List<Client> client;
```

This is a method wihch creates a special list to be displayed on the PDF:

```
private static void createList(Section subCatPart){

List list = new List(true, false, 10);

List.add(new ListItem("First point");
List.add(new ListItem("Second point");

SubCatPart.add(list);}
```

But it says that "List cannot instantiate the type List"( in the method createList).

Comment: You seem to be confusing `java.util.List` and `com.itextpdf.text.List`. These are two different classes with different purposes!

Comment: yes I know, that is the problem, my class Java recognize util.List and not itextpdf.text.List

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`List` is an interface. You can't instantiate it. Use any subclass like `ArrayList` like below

`List<Client> clientList = new ArrayList<Client>();`